# Appending data to GUI table

Tags: matlab, append, matlab-figure, updates, matlab-uitable

I have program to display data in a `uitable`:

```
data_plat = load('Data_Plat.mat');   
Database_All = data_plat.Database_All;   
data2 = table2cell(Database_All(strcmpi(Database_All.Plat, final_output), ...
                                        {'Plat', 'Nama', 'Jurusan', 'Status'}));   
set(handles.uitable1, 'Data', data2);
```

`final_output` is a number computed by the program which always changes because the program is processing video.

How can I invoke this code repeatedly such that data is added to the table without erasing (or replicating) what's already there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [`union`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/union.html) function.

Try changing the last line of your code to this:

```
handles.uitable1.Data = union(handles.uitable1.Data, data2);
```

Comment: yeah, something like that, but why data just set(show) in 1 column, how to make it show with 1 row every data,? my table have 4 column

Comment: @YusranMansyur 1) You probably need to transpose (`.'`) it. 2) Delete the 1st row? Please provide actual data if you want help. I can't really help you based on vague descriptions.

Comment: oh, sorry, my bad, my data just set in 1 column(downward), how to make it show normally,?

Comment: 2. its starting show data in row number 2, row number 1 is empty

Comment: No point in asking any further questions unless you're going to add ACTUAL data to your question reproducing the problem. See [mcve]. Good day!

Comment: u can see picture :  https://scontent.fsub2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/21442932_1727051760647332_1464414969_n.png?_nc_eui2=v1%3AAeE3bPqQPzh7fRgOxqTeQbtKbOHaX2q-LZ11hO2LBX2vEzo81h6vUrXOBxw2YekqF2pcE5Pg5-k135HQNBMlQp4J8fB5BrnKJwN998W5XzJt5A&oh=20bdbb0de701eee285b5352f1e4af2aa&oe=59B39816

Comment: ty for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply concatenate the data in the uitable with new data, then update the uitable. Just insert this line before last line of the code in your question:

```
data2 = [get(handles.uitable1, 'Data'); data2];
```

Comment: oh, ty for answer that, but, that code always adding, even same data, how about overwrite or not repeat if same data??

Comment: n when i insert that code, its starting adding in row line 5, how to make adding starting row line 1??